# Complexity of $Σ_n$ theory of $H(ω_2)$ under MM$^{++}$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

Under Woodin's $\mathbb{P}_\text{max}$ axiom (which is implied by MM$^{++}$), what is the complexity of the $Σ_n$ theory of $H(ω_2)$?  Same question for $Σ_n(I_\text{NS})$ (i.e. using the nonstationary ideal on $ω_1$).

Surprisingly, under large cardinal axioms, there is a generic extension of $V$ such that the theories of $H(ω_1)$ and $H(ω_2)$ have the same Turing degree.  Specifically, assuming a supercompact cardinal, some generic extension of $V$ satisfies Martin's Maximum$^{++}$ (MM$^{++}$).  In 2019, MM$^{++}$ was shown to imply Woodin's $\mathbb{P}_\text{max}$ axiom (which Woodin simply called "(*)") ([Martin’s Maximum++ implies Woodin’s Axiom (*)](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/MM_implies_star_Feb_2021.pdf) by David Aspero and and Ralf Schindler).  In turn, the $\mathbb{P}_\text{max}$ axiom (which is consistent relative to $ω$ Woodin cardinals, but was not initially known to hold in a generic extension of $V$) implies that the theories of $H(ω_1)$ and $H(ω_2)$ have the same Turing degree.

I am convinced that CH is true (as opposed to $c=ω_2$ under PFA), but it is interesting to explore other 'universes', and ask, under the axiom of choice, what happens if we try to minimize the number of 'pathologies' of size $ω_1$.  PFA and its extensions MM and MM$^{++}$ give a plausible answer.  MM$^{++}$ asserts that for every forcing $P$ preserving stationarity of subsets of $ω_1$, for every collection of $ω_1$ dense subsets of $P$, and for every collection of $ω_1$ names for stationary subsets of $ω_1$, there is a filter that meets all the dense subsets and realizes all the names by actual stationary sets.

Under ZF+AD, every subset of $ω_1$ is constructible from a real (and every real has a sharp), so $Σ_n^{H(ω_2)}$ (allowing $ω_1$ as a constant for $n=1$) and $Σ_n^{H(ω_2)}(I_\text{NS})$ have the same complexity as $Σ^1_{n+2}$, even allowing real parameters.  I do not know what happens under the $\mathbb{P}_\text{max}$ axiom.

Comment: What do you mean by, "What is the complexity?"

Comment: @MonroeEskew Complexity is the degree under many-one reducibility here.

Comment: But what kind of answer do you seek?  A description of how its degree relates to other well-known degrees?

Comment: @MonroeEskew Correct (see the last paragraph for how the answer may look like).

Comment: I don't know how much you would find this related to your question but in arXiv2101.07573 it is shown that there is a recursive signature L (given by declaring atomic the Delta_0-formulae, the lightface definable universally Baire sets, the formula for NS) such that in signature L the theory of H(\omega_2) assuming P_max is model complete and there is a recursive set A of axioms given by Pi_2-sentence of LK such that in any model M of MM^++ the L-theory of H(omega_2) is given by the above recursive set A and the non recursive set given by the Pi_1-sentences of L holding in the model.